# How to use Flask-Restless with a geographical database and connect it to an interface?

Tags: python, json, backend, flask-restful, flask-restless

I have thoroughly searched and I already know what to do (it is in the title). But the question here is: How do I start? Are there any examples of this? I need to have a geographical database that is connected to a Flask-Restless API.

How do I start?

Comment: I flagged this as `too broad`. It would be better if you divided it up into a bunch of smaller, discrete questions, like *what geo db has great python support?* *Is there a REST API in common usage for JSON-based APIs?* You might even find the answers to some of these questions already here. (hint, hint).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parsing values from a JSON file in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835559/parsing-values-from-a-json-file-in-python)

Comment: I tried to simplify it

Comment: It is not a duplicate. I simply do not know how to start doing this